# Checkbox widget and valuelistenablebuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to have a list of checkboxes. I want to be able to reset the checked boxes by pushing a button from another widget. Here is the code for the checkbox class

```
class CheckBox extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckBox({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<CheckBox> createState() => _CheckboxState();
}

class _CheckboxState extends State<CheckBox> {
  bool? isChecked = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: locator.get<LocalData>().resetParagraphs,
        builder: (context, boolvalue, __) {
          return Checkbox(
              tristate: false,
              value: (boolvalue && isChecked!) ? false : isChecked,
              onChanged: (
                bool? value,
              ) {
                if (boolvalue) {
                  locator.get<LocalData>().setresetParagrahMode();
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    isChecked = value;
                  });
                }
              });
        });
  }
}
```

and here is the code for the ChangeNotifier class

```
class LocalData with ChangeNotifier {

  ValueNotifier<bool> resetParagraphs = ValueNotifier(false);


  void setresetParagrahMode() {
    resetParagraphs.value = !resetParagraphs.value;
    log(resetParagraphs.value.toString());

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

So what it does is it resets the check boxes, but when I click on one of the boxes again once it has been reset, all the boxes that I previously clicked on get checked again. So If I reset 3 boxes, I reset, and I click in one of the 3 boxes again, it checks all the 3 boxes again. My logic was that if boolvalue is true (reset button has been pushed) and the checkbox is true (checked), then set the value of checkbox to false. Else, continue as normal. I spend some hours figuring out but I couldn't fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: locator.get<LocalData>().resetParagraphs,
        builder: (context, boolvalue, __) {
          if (boolvalue) {
            isChecked = false;
          }
          return Checkbox(
              tristate: false,
              value: boolvalue && isChecked! ? !isChecked! : isChecked,
              onChanged: (
                value,
              ) {
                isChecked = value;
                if (boolvalue) {
                  locator.get<LocalData>().setresetParagrahMode();
                }

                setState(() {});
              });
        });
  }
```

Not sure how I made it to work, but it does work! Hopefully the solution helps someone else.

Comment: Please mark this as an answer,